# Como verificar atualização no banco de dados a partir de um browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer uma página que atualize a `<div>` (que tem o conteúdo trazido do banco de dados) automaticamente assim que for inserido algum valor (assim como nesse site).
Usei o `setInterval` para atualizar (com Ajax) a `<div>`  a cada 10 segundos, mas não gostei do resultado, pois eu acho desnecessário fazer requisições a cada dez segundos.
Então queria fazer uma verificação antes, e caso tenha alguma atualização no banco executar meu script e atualizar a `<div>`
**Como posso verificar se algum valor foi inserido no banco de dados?**

Comment: Sinceramente esse é o jeito mais errado de se fazer uma requisição assíncrona. Recomendo você estudar WebSockets. http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/.

Comment: Sei que essa é a maneira mais errada, por isso pedi ajuda, valeu @LuizPicolo!, vou dar uma estudada sim :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O modelo adotado pelos servidores web antes do HTML 5 são requisições unidirecionais, o que na prática significa que o servidor nunca consegue mandar uma requisição para o cliente, apenas o contrário. O servidor só consegue enviar dados a um cliente na resposta de uma requisição.

### Estratégia atual: Polling

A tática que você está utilizando se chama [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29), que consiste em perguntar ao servidor de tempos em tempos se "tem alguma coisa nova". Essa tática é a única possível quando um dos lados não pode iniciar uma requisição.

### Usando HTML5: Websockets

O HTML 5 introduziu [websockets](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets). Essa tecnologia permite que o cliente abra uma bidirecional com o servidor, e portanto receba ou envie dados a qualquer instante.

A ultima padronização de websockets é o [rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) e é suportado pelos seguintes browsers:

- Internet Explorer 10+
- Mozilla Firefox 4+
- Safari 5+
- Google Chrome 4+
- Opera 11+

Caso seja possível para a sua aplicação se limitar a esses browsers, você pode utilizar websockets.

### Usando JAVA

Também é possivel utilizar um applet Java para fazer a comunicação bidirecional. [Essa página mostra um pequeno exemplo, com código fonte](http://jliusun.bradley.edu/%7Ejiangbo/cliser/Socket/). O método de funcionamento é similar aos websockets - Uma conexão a parte da requisição web é aberta com o servidor.

### Usando flash

Talvez seja possível usar flash também. Não tenho certeza.

Comment: Você tem alguma ideia de como eu faria para consultar o banco com WebSocket's? eu deu uma lida nesse artigo http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/ mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: @Odair Tem que implementar duas partes: O servidor (na sua linguagem predileta) e o cliente (em javascript). Olhando por cima, o exemplo mostra só a parte do cliente. [Esse outro exemplo(http://turim.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/html-5-comunicacao-bidirecional-utilizando-websocket/) Mostra o lado do servidor em java, mas vai depender do que tu tá usando.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara, vou dar uma lida e estudar melhor isso.

Comment: @Odair as ordens :-)

Answer (score 1):

Se a informação desejada depende de tabelas específicas, poderia ser criada uma Trigger na respectiva tabela (chamarei de tabela A) que, ao ter um registro inserido, atualizado ou removido, grava o log em uma outra tabela (Tabela B). Sua rotina iria consultar a Tabela B para saber se houve alteração nos dados e, caso afirmativo, atualizaria sua DIV.

Outra forma seria agendar um JOB (SQL Server) que verificaria a alteração dos dados na Tabela A e este iria popular a Tabela B sinalizando a ocorrência de alteração no banco de dados.

Foi o que consegui vislumbrar agora, rapidamente, mas devem existir outras formas também.